# Статическая линковка libdl

Tags: c++, linux, c, static

Извиняюсь, за возможно не очень умный вопрос, но все же. Возможно ли статически собрать программу, если в ее коде присутствует вызовы функций библиотеки libdl (кстати, она ведь бывает libdl.a, или только libdl.so?), такие как dlopen, dlsym и т.п. ?

Comment: Да, это возможно

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch, не подскажите как?

Comment: как линковать библиотеку?

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch, мне кажется и так очевидно что требуется, разве нет? Если знаешь - по шагам распиши что делать ( где взять libdl.a, а libdl.so, как обойти вызовы dlopen, dlsym, но при этом есстественно нужно чтобы библиотека использующая libdl-функции функционировала полностью. Я вот - не знаю как так сделать, по этому т спрашиваю этот вопрос), а если не знаешь - зачем вообще внимание привлекаешь,  и пишешь что можно. Ну ОЧЕВИДНО же, что если можно, то мне нужно узнать как это сделать

Comment: какие мы дерзкие однако)) давайте я вам кое что объясню: линковка - один из базовых этапов сборки, наряду с препроцесингом, трансляцией и компиляцией. Вы не можете собрать мало-мальски сложную программу без линковки. Если вам не знакома какая либо из этих стадий, то советую открыть учебники (можно Прата или С++ для чайников). Линковка библиотеки зависит от компилятора, например для g++ она осуществляется с помощью флагов -l или -L. Ну а подробности чем они отличаются или как их правильно использовать - найдете в документации к компилятору

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch, вопрос про конкретную библиотку libdl. Есть ли версия libdl.a? Если есть, то как мне ее получить (из исходников собрать? Если да, то откуда и с какими парметрами, желательно ссылка). И второй вопрос, как быть с теми функциями библиотеки libdl  (dlopen, dlsym и т.п.), которые фигурируют в коде программы, которую я хочу собрать статически?

Comment: не понимаю в чем проблема с вызовами функций. Что касается libdl.a - ищите среди библиотек, вроде она идет вместе с компилятором

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch, так программа же вывалится в ошибку, когда дойдет до места вызова dlopen той динамической библиотеки, которой не окажется на компьютере. А мне нужно - что все работало. Вот основная проблема(

Comment: вы издеваетесь что ли? Конечно, если вы слинкуете динамически, а потом перенесете исполняемый файл на другой компьютер без нужной библиотеки, то ничего работать не будет. На то есть статическая линковка.